# Backbone Tempting with Underscore is rendering one attribute in template but not the other

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to make a simple list in Backbone but am running into an odd problem. This is my first time using underscore templating, so I'm not sure if that's the reason. It seems like it's a simple problem, but I can't figure it out.

I have a backbone model with the attributes `name` and `band`. When I only have it render `name`, like below, it succeeds in rendering a list of the names.

```
var template = _.template("<h2><%= name %></h2><br><h3></h3>")
```

This renders fine. But when I have any iteration with the `band` variable in, it throws me the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: band is not defined`, and I can't figure out why. It's getting the reference for name from the attributes object I'm passing it. Why does it see `name` but not `band`?

Full code below.

```
var Album = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {name: "The Album", band: "The Band"}
});
var albumOne = new Album({name: "SGT PEPPER", band: "The Beatles"});
//Eight more album instances here

var template = _.template("<h2><%= name %></h2><br><h3><%=band%></h3>")

var AlbumCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Album,
    initialize: function(){
        this.render()           
    },
    render: function(){
        this.each(function(item){
            new tempView(item);
        });
    }
});
var tempView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    template: template(),

    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    el: $("#shuff"),
    render: function(){ 
        this.$el.append(template(this.attributes))
    }
});

window.myCollection = new AlbumCollection([albumOne, albumTwo, albumThree, albumFour,albumFive,albumSix,albumSeven,albumEight,albumNine]);
window.myCollection.render();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The breaking point is not your render method, but the `template` attribute.

You're assigning an evaluated template with `template: template()` but there is no `band` on the global context (`window.band`) and the evaluation breaks. It works with only a `name`variable because [`window.name` is in fact a valid property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name).

Try `template: template` and your example will run http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/6j58kf2w/

*Note : I must add that mixing a model and a view will probably lead to unforeseen problems. I would advise to try and keep the models as ignorant of the views as you can.*